# Esta bien mi plantemiento para resolver este problema en SLE2 o PSeInt?

Tags: funciones, pseudocódigo, sl

Dado un vector A de m elementos numéricos (entero o real) y un valor K del
mismo tipo de los elementos del vector, se quiere saber la primera posición
donde se encuentra el valor K dentro del vector (si es que existe).

Mi idea que intento plazmar es la siguiente (Ojo. Este codigo es SLE2. Tambien puedo ponerlo en PSeInt):

```
var 
  a : vector[10] numerico 
  k : numerico 
  i : numerico 
inicio 
  cls()

  k = 0
  i = 1

  desde i = 1 hasta 10 
  {
    imprimir ("Ingrese un valor en posición, ", i)
    leer (a[i])
  }

  imprimir ("Ingrese el valor que quiere saber su posición: ")
  leer (k)
```

**Ojo... para este ejercicio debo utilizar funciones y procedimiento (aplicar subrutinas)**

En esa parte del código estoy estancado. Pues, no se como en la **subrutina** (o como hacer una subrutina) voy a aplicar una **funcion o procedimiento** que me haga ciertas condiciones para saber donde se encuentra el valor de **k**. Sucede que tengo un vector donde estoy ingresando valores y si yo, por medio de **k**, quiero saber donde esta **x** numero no se como aplicar que ese vector entre en la subrutina.

Estuve pensando en hacer una función que pase los valores del **vector a** y de **k por valor** para asi tomar esos valores en la subrutina y aplicar mis condiciones en la subrutina y saber la posicion de **k**, para asi devolver un valor al **codigo principal**.

Agradeceria orientación en cuanto a mi lógica y mi planteamiento de mi caso... :)

Answer (score 0):

Se pregunta si el número coincide con la posición, y en caso afirmativo se imprime un cartel que dice dónde lo encontró:

```
    elNumeroEsta : logico = FALSE
    .
    .
    .
    imprimir("Ingrese el valor que quiere saber su posición: ")
    leer (k)
    
    desde i=1 hasta 10{
        si (k == a[i]){
            imprimir("El número está en el indice ",i,", en la posición ",(i))
            elNumeroEsta = TRUE
        }
    }
    
    si (elNumeroEsta == FALSE){
        imprimir("El número no está")
    }
fin
```